# In Academic writing: usage of OF

Tags: prepositional-phrases, writing, inversion

Here I have the following paragraph, (this is from the beginning of paragraph)

> *Of*  these approaches, the model driven categories opt for pre-defined model libraries (AAA, 1999; BBB, 1998).  Among other changes are the recent presentations of a building reconstruction approach by CCC (2010) adopting Bayesian Decision rule to optimize parametric blocks placed on 2D-supports, and an introduction of generative statistics by DDD (2013) to a reconstruction scheme, where pre-defined primitives have been combined and merged into an entire roof.

[Here, AAA, BBB,CCC and DDD are names of the researchers]

*My questions are, in academic writing, is it common to start a sentence (actually a paragraph) with OF and does this paragraph is well accepted even in higher impact factor journals.*

or any suggestion from Native English speakers are also welcome, because I have been recommended to get their support.

Comment: Starting with “of” seems fine to me for academic writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely correct to start a sentence with "of" in academic writing (or any English prose). We can always begin a sentence with a conjunction. The form of the first sentence in your paragraph is:

**Conjunction with a dependent clause** ("Of these approaches")
followed by
**main clause** ("the model driven categories opt for pre-defined model libraries (AAA, 1999; BBB, 1998).")

It is a correct sentence.

(I also note that this form is used to begin many paragraphs in James Berger's scholarly paper about Bayesian analysis.)

There is a grammatical error in the second sentence in your paragraph, though:

> adopting Bayesian Decision rule to optimize

should read:

> adopting **the** Bayesian Decision rule to optimize `(if there is one Bayesian Decision rule)`

or

> adopting Bayesian Decision **rules** to optimize `(if there are more than one Bayesian Decision rule)`

*Edit to answer your question below:*

It is good flow (continuation) and correct to start the second sentence with "Among other changes". "Among" tells us there are more changes beyond the changes discussed in sentences 1 and 2. "Other changes" also clarifies that sentence 1 and sentence 2 are about **different** changes.

If we left out "Among other changes are", then the reader would face some confusion:

1. It may not be clear that the building reconstruction approach by CCC in sentence 2, **is not part of** the pre-defined model libraries in sentence 1.
2. It may not be clear **how** the building reconstruction approach by CCC in sentence 2 **is related** to the pre-defined model libraries in sentence 1.

(Sentence 2 would also lack a subject and verb!)

Comment: thank you for good answer with examples. Also, it helps if you tell about this phrase "Among other changes are the recent presentations of a building reconstruction approach ..." is also fully agree with academic journal papers? why it is written like that, is it just to get continuation or ..? thanks again

Comment: No problem! I edited my answer to address "Among other changes".